# При вызове метода Add для переменной List<T> типа заменяются значения её членов, если используется один и тот же объект

Tags: c#

При выполнении данного кода, метод `masList.Add(masStringOneItem);` в конце внешнего цикла спокойно добавляет новоиспечённую переменную во внутреннем цикле, то есть переменную массива строк `masStringOneItem`, но меня волнует вопрос — правильно ли, что я на каждую итерацию внешнего цикла создаю новую переменную массива строк, или это нормально?

```
public List<string[]> GetDataForComboBox(string nameOfTable)
    {
        List<DbDataRecord> arrList = new List<DbDataRecord>();
        SetCommandTextSelectBySecondaryKey(nameOfTable);
        arrList = GetTableData(CreateDataReaderVariable());
        List<string[]> masList = new List<string[]>();
        if (arrList[0].FieldCount != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrList.Count; i++)
            {
                string[] masStringOneItem = new string[arrList[0].FieldCount];
                //masList.Add();
                //masList[i].SetValue(arrList[i].GetValue(0).ToString(), 0);
                //masList[i].SetValue(arrList[i].GetValue(1).ToString(), 1);
                for (int j=0; j < arrList[0].FieldCount; j++)
                {
                    masStringOneItem[j] = arrList[i].GetValue(j).ToString();
                }
                masList.Add(masStringOneItem);
            }
        }
        return masList;
    }
```

Почему меня волнует данный вопрос, так это потому-что если я создам данную переменную до внешнего цикла (сразу после `if`), то при вызове метода `Add()` у объекта `List<T>` `masList` заменяются все его члены и их значения на те что у переменной `masStringOneItem`. Если есть более правильное решение чем я нашёл, то подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Создание новых экземляров `string[]` внутри цикла - правильно, иначе Вы будете добавлять в список ссылку на один и тот же объект. Уберите `new List<DbDataRecord>()` из первой строчки.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо, привычка создавать так объекты.
По поводу создания новых экземпляров... Старая переменная с таким же именем куда девается при таком вот цикличном создании?

Comment: "... пришлось целый час объяснять ему, почему вода мокрая, а трава зеленая; и куда девается земля, когда в ней дырка." О'Генри. Время жизни этой переменной - одна итерация цикла. А ссылку на созданный `string[]` Вы добавляете в список.

Comment: @Igor Благодарю вас за столь скорые и полезные ответы!

Comment: @Igor оформите ответом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создание новых экземляров `string[]` внутри цикла - правильно, иначе Вы будете добавлять в список ссылку на один и тот же объект.

> Старая переменная с таким же именем куда девается при таком вот
>   цикличном создании?

Время жизни этой переменной - одна итерация цикла. А ссылку на созданный `string[]` Вы добавляете в список.

N.B.

Уберите `new List<DbDataRecord>()` из первой строчки - созданный объект не используется, так как `arrList` присваивается новое значение двумя строчками ниже.

```
SetCommandTextSelectBySecondaryKey(nameOfTable);
List<DbDataRecord> arrList = GetTableData(CreateDataReaderVariable());
...
```